# Developing Activity Diagram for Back End Application

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I am developing a web based back-end application. In this back-end, I can View, Add, Edit, and Delete information. There is a form and a table positioned under the form.
First, the application will load information into the table. When I choose to edit a row, I click an "Edit" link in the row and the information will be loaded into the form. Then I can change the information and save it.

In my Activity Diagram for "Edit", should I start from the user clicking the "Edit" link or start from loading information to the table?

I am a little confused because this loading information step is already included in "View" Activity Diagram.

Answer (score 0):

well i think it depends.if you draw all the roles in partitions then you can use "the loading action" only once and show transition from this to other activities like if you create partitions for view,edit and delete link then you can show loading of the table only once and then show transition from it directly to "edit row" activity in edit link partition and likewise for other activities too.needless to say that you have to use branching accordingly.you could have posted the rough diagram you created so that improvements could be made.